# Job Executable Oracle 8i

Tags: database, oracle, jobs, oracle8i

I have to set a job that execute every day the script for export:

```
begin
        DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_job
        (job_name => 'EXPDP_FULLBCK',
        repeat_interval => 'FREQ=DAILY; INTERVAL=1; BYDAY=MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI,SAT,SUN; BYHOUR=21',
        job_type => 'EXECUTABLE',
        job_action => 'E:\F\export\scripts\exp_dp_dcmneapp.cmd',
        enabled => TRUE,
        comments => 'Take EXPDP full Backup'
        );
end;
/
```

But i need to use this on an oracle 8i but DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_job not work

How i can convert?

Comment: You cannot run external executables directly in 8i. have a look at workaround [here](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:::::P11_QUESTION_ID:952229840241)

Answer (score 3):

The DBMS_SCHEDULER package/feature was not introduced till 10g. I was going to tell you to check if the DBA_JOBS package exists on 8i, but DBA_JOBS did not support executing OS scripts.  So instead of invoking export from the database invoke it from the OS using cron (UNIX/Linux) to run the batch script to perform the export.  Windows also has a scheduler.